# WPS "distance" function with geographic coordinates

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wps

I need to use WPS to calculate distance between two geometries, the geometries are represented in EPSG:4326.

The geo:distance function of WPS tells:
"Returns the minimum distance between two geometries. Measurement is given in the input units, so geographic coordinates are not recommended."

So, how can I do that? Must I convert the coordinates to UTM? if yes, how?

My environment is: PostGIS, Geoserver, and OpenLayers

Comment: Is the geo:distance process made by yourself?

Comment: No, it's from Geoserver.